# String variable in Xlsxwriter Python

Tags: python, excel, tkinter, xlsxwriter

I am kind of new to python, and I was making a program with Tkinter that would let me write things in another excel file without actually having to open the Excel file.

From tkinter, I added an Entry box that I would have to write a value, and a button, that would use xlsxwriter to write the value inside the excel format.

I have tried

```
    name_entry = StringVar()
    name_get = name_entry.get()
    e1 = Entry(root, textvariable = name_entry)
    b1 = Button(root, text = "Create")
    e1.pack()
    b1.bind("<Button-1>", create)
    b1.pack()
```

the function 'create' is

```
    def create(event):
        workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(0, "2016" + str(name_get))
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
        worksheet.write(0, 0, 'name')
        worksheet.write(1, 0, str(name_get))
        workbook.close
```

When I run the program and write something in the entry and press the 
button(b1), the excel file that it creates only has the 'name' written in 
row = 0 and column = 0, but I don't have the name I wrote in the entry box in row = 1 and column = 0. Also, the name of the created file will only be saved as "2016", not "2016" + str(name_get), the value that I had written in the entry box.

Other than that, the program does not have any errors

How can I have the value written in the entry box to be written in the excel file?

Also, is it possible to create an extension of an excel file (.csv file, for example) in xlsxwriter?

Thank you so much for reading my question, and I would truly appreciate some advice!

Comment: `Button` has `command=` so you don't need `bind`

Comment: I am not familiarized with `xlsxwriter` module, but maybe if you try to replace `str(name_get)` by `str(type(name_get))` you will get the type of object printed in the excel sheet. That is useful info you can use to search somemore information.

Comment: you have to use `name_entry.get()` in function. `name_get` doesn't work as you expect - it keep only value returned by `name_entry.get()` executed at start (when `Entry` was empty)

Answer (score 0):

There may be other issues but this line isn't correct:

```
   workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(0, "2016" + str(name_get))
```

The [Workbook constructor takes the parameters:](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/workbook.html#constructor) `Workbook(filename[, options])`

So that line should probably be:

```
   workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("2016" + str(name_get))
```

> Also, is it possible to create an extension of an excel file (.csv file, for example) in xlsxwriter?

No.

XlsxWriter only creates xlsx files and the file extension on the output file should be `.xlsx` or Excel will complain when it opens the file.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are trying to pass a string variable to the worksheet.write method.

This can be accomplished using the `worksheet.write_string()` method.

http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html?highlight=write_string#write_string

ex. -

```
name_entry = ''
worksheet.write_string(1,0, name_entry)
```